# IBM MQ : Do I have to lock ISession objects in multi-threaded context?

Tags: ibm-mq, message-queue, xms

In the documentation I see the following sentence:

> A Session object can be used on only a single thread at any one time.
>   ([Source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.xms.doc/xms_cthrdmod.html))

Does this mean that if my application is multi-threaded, and if my `ISession` objects are accessible for multiple threads, that I have to lock `ISession` objects whenever I use them so these objects are accessed synchronously?

I use `ISession` objects when Sending messages (here I'm in a multi-threaded context, so should I lock ISession objects here?)

Example code:

```
var textMessage = _session.CreateTextMessage(message);
producer.Send(textMessage);
```

Comment: You can always create new Session object in a different thread

Comment: I don't want to create Session object whenever I have to send messages. These sessions are created during app init, and I re-use them. This because creation of Connection and Session objects are time consuming

Comment: Then you will have to synchronize the session object and lock is a way to do it